# Python object.append from for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append dictionary values to a list from a for loop, though it is only picking up the last value. Please advise, here is my code:

```
for line in obj:
    test = float(line['value'])
    print(test)

a = []
a.append(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `append` is outside the loop.  Indentation matters in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Huh! You have messed up the indentation. Indentation is **VERY IMPORTANT** in python. `a` list is outside the `for-loop` hence it would only have the last value of `test`. IT should be inside the `for-loop`.

It should be like this -

```
a = []
for line in obj:
    test = float(line['value'])
    print(test)
    a.append(test)
print a
```